# Get an email notification from Google once the app is live; after publishing it to the Play Store (Android)

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to receive an email update from Google once the app is live after we publish it. It can become quite handy in case we want to update our users at a specific time about the update.

Answer (score 25):

**As of - 24.03.2023**

> Google Play Console -> Setup -> Notifications

Activate `Get notified when your app or store listing update goes live`.

Comment: This has since changed, it's now Setup -> Notifications, from the All Apps page.

Comment: I updated the answer according to the recent changes in Google Play Console, noticed and raised by @Seth.

Comment: Email never arrive, I had to shoot an email to playstore support, lost a big amount of time trying to get thhose email, I receive the app check report though.

Answer (score 5):

With the new Play Console, it is now
**Google Play Console -> Settings -> Preferences -> Notifications From Play Console -> App updates**

Comment: Did you manage to receive one email with this method ? Or two (approval / refusal)... I never did.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Play Console:

Go to Settings -> Email Notifications

In Alert dropdown menu - choose "I want to receive alert for all/some of my apps".

Comment: That option is already enabled in my settings option. However, i never receive any emails whenever my new app build is live.

Answer (score 0):

No such option at the moment IMHO

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 this has been moved.
First, make sure you're on the All Apps page.

The All Apps page, has a sidebar that has these navigation items:

- All Apps
- Inbox
- Policy Status
- Users and Permissions
  ...
- Setup

If instead there is a back button with the label "All apps" tap that until you see a sidebar with the above navigation items.

From here navigate to:
Setup -> Notifications

Then scroll down to "App Updates" and check the box next to "Email"

Comment: Did you manage to receive one email with this method ? Or two (approval / refusal)... I never did.